# std::unordered_map initialization

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

When I access an element in [std::unordered_map using operator []](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) for the first time, it is automatically created. What (if any) are guarantees about its initialization? (It is guaranteed to be value initialized, or only to be constructed)?

Example:

```
std::unordered_map<void *, size_t> size;
char *test = new char[10];
size[test] += 10;
```

Is size[test] guaranteed to be 10 at the end of this sequence?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is size[test] guaranteed to be 10 at the end of this sequence?

Yes.
In the last line of your code, `size[test]` value-initializes the element to `T()`, or in this case `size_t()`:

> C++11 23.4.4.3 map element access [map.access]
>
> `T& operator[](const key_type& x)`;
>
> 1 Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, **T()**) into the map.

As to `T()`, the exact language is a somewhat involved, so I'll try to quote the relevant bits:

> C++11 8.5.16 The semantics of initializers are as follows.
>
> — **If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.**

---

> 8.5.7 To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type ...
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type ...
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

---

> 8.5.5 To **zero-initialize** an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), **the object is set to the value 0 (zero)**, taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;

Comment: I have read that part of docs, but I was not sure of implications. What does "default-constructed" mean for an integral type like size_t? (Can you quote a standard, preferably?)

Comment: @Suma: integral types aren't class types, so they don't have constructors. Value-initializing those types equals zero-initialization. (Chapter 8.)

Comment: @KerrekSB are you sure you're not confusing C++ with Java? Builtins do not default-construct to zero.

Comment: "Value-initializing those types equals zero-initialization" this is clear, but the operator [] docs are not talking about value initialization, only about default construction. I am no standard expert, I guess you are right and it means the same thing, but is it possible to show step by step by standard quotes?

Comment: As you have wrote in the previous version, the [] guarantees default construction. Now you are talking about value initialization, but I do not see where the guarantee of value initialization comes from in case of this operator. (I would very much want this to be true, it makes my histogram building code a lot simpler, but I would like to prevent relying on some undefined behaviour).

Comment: Wtf? Is this new to C++11? I was sure builtins had no default values, no-overhead principle.

Comment: @spraff: value-initialization entails zeroing, and the Standard guarantees value-initialization here. In *general* built-in are left as is, but in the special case of the STL containers, they are value-initialized. Likewise, should you call `std::vector<int> v(10);` you would obtain 10 zeroes.

Comment: @spraff: Value-initialisation was new in C++03 (one of a very few changes from C++98).

Comment: Ugh. Can't say I approve of that. Constructing a vector is now O(n).

Answer (score 0):

What's the difference? Value-initialization for class-type objects entails default construction, so the answer is "both". For a map `<K, V>`, the new object will be initialized with `V()`.

All standard containers initialize new elements with value- or direct-initialization (the latter possibly through a copy construction). It is not possible for new standard container elements to be in an "uninitialized" state (i.e. there is no mechanism that *default*-initializes elements).

Comment: I assumed "constructed" in the sense like when I use the int member variable in a class, the default class constructor does not initialize the value. I guess you are right, but is value initialization guaranteed by the "default constructed" phrase? What if V will be POD? Will it be default constructed (i.e. uninitialized) or value initialized?

Comment: @Suma: `V` is value-initialized, so if `V` is fundamental, it's zero-initialized, and if it's class-type, it is default-constructed. For compound types you apply the rules recursively.