# Is ++map[element] well defined?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std

The square bracket operator in associative containers (map, unordered map) will insert an element in the map if it doesn't exist. In case the mapped value is an integer, like

```cpp
std::map<std::string, int> map; // Or std::unordered_map
```

is calling the pre-increment operator well defined even in the case `[]` triggers the insertion of a new element?

I'm suspecting it should be ok, since in both ordered and unordered maps the standard mandates that a new element of type `T` is inserted as `T()` i.e. value initialization which means that the number zero is inserted.

Comment: [yes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). there is even exactly the same example there - `std::map<std::string, int>  word_map; ... ++word_map[w];`

Comment: @EOF Yes! Thanks for linking this

Comment: There are also a good number of other duplicates, this is a common question about c++: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8943261/3185968 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62656874/3185968

Answer (score -1):

For the class template `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` the subscript operator returns a reference to an object of the mapped type

```
T& operator[](const key_type& x);

mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& k);
```

So the referenced object may be changed provided that the increment operator is defined for the mapped type.

The action of the operator is equivalent to

```
return try_emplace(k).first->second;
```

Comment: Isn't this the subscript operator of unordered map https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at ?

Comment: @LorahAttkins I've never downvoted an answer that deserved the downvote more.

Comment: @LorahAttkins It is strange that in the C++ Standard the subscript operator for std::unordered_map is described at the end of the class definition while for std::map in the beginning of the class definition.:) So I have thought that it is absent for std::unoedered_map.:)